# I need to understand what it is nEpoch in sample

Tags: java, deeplearning4j

I am running the example number

`[96] org.deeplearning4j.examples.convolution.objectdetection.HouseNumberDetection`.

It's in the training phase and I was wondering why this sentence keeps coming up:

```
o.d.o.l.ScoreIterationListener - Score at iteration 352 is 2.6203769938063846
```

Specifically, I do not understand the number 352, in this case, if by invoking the sentence that causes the above, that is, this

```
model.fit(train, nEpochs);
```

nEpochs is instantiated as

```
int nEpochs = 20;
```

From ignorance and wanting to understand, shouldn't there be at most 20 scores? 20 iterations to train and after that, save the model?

I am using latest version

```
    <version>1.0.0-beta6</version>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterations aren't the same thing as epochs. An epoch is when all your data has been used once. An iteration, in DL4J is when a mini batch has been used. So if you have 100 examples in you dataset and you use 10 each in your mini batches, then you will have 10 iterations per epoch.

Comment: Thank you Paul. I started the execution six hours ago, still running! When is it going to finish? Right now, i can see this: o.d.o.l.ScoreIterationListener - Score at iteration 2608 is 1.1010725003566744 The sample is running in a macbook pro 8-Core Intel Core i9 2.4Ghz, 32GB DDR4, in cpu mode.

Comment: This example takes quite a while to finish on a cpu. Additionally the MacBook pro can't really cool that cpu for long run times so it is also downclocking.